# Renderers in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

How can I find the object that can render a control?

For example:
- **sap.m.Image** gets rendered by **sap.m.ImageRenderer**

I can't seem to find it for other controls like **sap.ui.unified.CalendarAppointment**

Any tips or documentation on this?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of `CalendarAppointment` the rendering is done in the `CalendarRowRenderer`: [See relevant line of code](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.unified/src/sap/ui/unified/CalendarRowRenderer.js#L96)

How I found that out? There is a comment [here](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.unified/src/sap/ui/unified/CalendarAppointment.js#L17) that states

> The rendering must be done in the Row collecting the appointments. (Because there are different visualizations possible.)

---

**Rule of thumb:** If a control is only used in an aggregation of another control, there is a chance that the other control is in charge of rendering.